# Running different PHP CLI version depending on working path

Tags: php, apache-2.4, php-fpm, command-line-interface

I set up PHP-FPM to have different versions of PHP for different folders. This was necessary due to legacy code and was achieved using the apache's `.htaccess`.

My question is: does anyone have a simple elegant way to do this in CLI? I was thinking maybe have a file in the folder indicating the desired version of PHP to run, but unsure of how to go about it.

My expected result is that when I run `php ...` in folder A, it runs with PHP 7.4 and when I do the same `php ...` in folder B, it runs with PHP 8.1

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your PHP versions are installed in different paths, e.g.:

- php 7.4 is in `/usr/local/php74/bin`
- php 8.1 is in `/usr/local/php81/bin`
- etc

Create a script `php` that looks for a `.phppath` file in each directory that describes which php binary to use. Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This sets the default if not otherwise specified
phppath=/usr/local/php81/bin/php

if [ -f .phppath ]; then
  phppath=$(cat .phppath)
fi


exec $phppath "$@"
```

Put this in your `$PATH` somewhere and you should be all set. In directories where you want, say, PHP 7.4, create an appropriate `.phppath` file:

```
echo /usr/local/php74/bin/php > .phppath
```

---

Note that as written, this only finds `.phppath` *in the current directory*. It won't find it if you're working in a subdirectory. That's a solvable problem, but it's left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: wonderful! actually it is exactly what I need, the extra exercise wasn't necessary. I think the path should be written into `> .phpversion` instead of `> .phppath`. Thank you!

Comment: i think there is still a bug in your script, checking for `.phppath`, but reading from `.phpversion`. I would have different names for variable and filename for clarity especially for new folks trying to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, good catch. Updating.